# How to Configure IPTV and Ethernet

Tags: vlan

My network is currently set up where:
the ONT gets internet from the OSP,
The ONT leads to the router
[I had to set up the VLAN inside of the router settings to allow it to use LAN port 4 to sent TV signal to the TV Box]

I want to send more than the TV signal through this ethernet cable so that I can use an extra router as an AP to also connect my smart TV (for netflix) and my computer.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

VLAN
[image]

Comment: Can you show the current VLAN configuration on the ONT, and specify what router/AP model you want to connect (specifically, does it support VLANs itself)?

Comment: Hello, I'm Not sure abt the ONT, but the settings on the router that i had to set up were:

Comment: Hello, I'm Not sure abt the ONT, but the settings on the router that i had to set up were: VLAN 10-Tagged-0 (on {internet} port). VOIP 30-tagged-port 4. IPTV-untagged port 4. Router connected to ONT is linksys WRT 1900 ACS, and router i'd like to set as AP is AC2200. I'm sorry, the pictures I uploaded did not actually upload

Comment: I was able to upload the pictures now, so you can have a clearer vision